# Google Colaboratory- Blank page Issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory- Blank page Issue

I get a blank page when opening a specific google colab notebook, when I created a new one or tried to open an old notebook they opened with no problem. This notebook was working well but suddenly when I tried to open it the next day it shows a blank page!

I tried several browsers, but all of them worked fine with any google colab notebook except this, it always shows a blank page...

Could someone tell me what could I do?

Image number 1 shows the console
[image]
Note: when trying to open this notebook, google drive also doesn't respond anymore. and shows me image number 2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once try below steps

-->Try to open in incognito tab. If not solved.

-->Clear all cookies of chrome & Try to open file again.

Comment: Thank you, but neither the incognito tab nor clearing the cookies or cache files helped me

Comment: I solved it with Ctrl+Shift+R after clearing the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing all cookies, allow cookies for colab url. Another is go to inspect, select gear, uncheck enable JavaScript source maps and also uncheck enable CSS source maps.